# Python; scientific notation string to number

Tags: python, csv

I am currently converting a file from csv to xlsx. The problem is that the data is default converted all to strings. How can I convert the numbers (typically shown as +1.50000000000E+009 or " +1.50000000000E+009" (leading space) from string to number representations. I've tried typecasting and general workarounds but nothing works.

The "IF" statement is because the csv file has a header.

```
def csv_to_excel(csv_path, delimiter, delimiter_txt, excel_path, excel_title):
csv_file = open(csv_path, 'r')
csv.register_dialect(delimiter_txt, delimiter=delimiter)

reader = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect=delimiter_txt)

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.title = excel_title
for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
    for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
        column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
        if row_index > 3:
            ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = float(cell)
        else:
            ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = cell
        print(cell)
        print(type(cell))
wb.save(filename = excel_path)
csv_file.close()
```

csv_to_excel('file.csv',',','comma','file.xlsx','data')

Thanks! Any help would be great!

Comment: `float('+1.50000000000E+009')` works

Comment: It looks like you're already using `float(cell)` which is what the current answers are suggesting. What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Typecasting should work - as the answers have suggested. Could it be that your second `ws.cell = ...` does not have a typecast operation like the first one does? You have one `ws.cell ... = float(cell)` and another just `ws.cell ... = cell`

Comment: Also note about printing `type(cell)` - if you dont do a `cell = float(cell)` somewhere in the script, cell will not be changed from a string to a float. Just calling `float(cell)` does not actually modify `cell`

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. The problem that I guess is truly the root of the problem is what @ChildishJack said. I would like the values within the new .xlsx file to be numbers (and the first three lines of text for the headers) themselves, not merely loading them into memory as floats and not changing their inherent type. How would I change their type permanently

Comment: So is your issue that the values in the sheet when opening the .xlsx are strings and not floats?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using `float()`.

```
>>> float("+1.50000000000E+009")
>>> 1500000000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You **should** use `float()` :

```
float("+1.50000000000E+009")
```

you can also use `eval()`, however this could be potentially *dangerous* if you do not know for certain the type of input you'll be passing as a parameter.

```
eval("+1.50000000000E+009")
```

Both return `1500000000.0`

Comment: If you know that it will be a number, I would recommend against using `eval()` because you are accepting input from a potentially untrusted source. The risk of an arbitrary execution vulnerability does not seem worth it for this case because `float()` works the same.

Comment: @arewm I would tend to agree, as `eval()` does evaluate python expressions, I'll update my answer.

Comment: `float()` is the way to go. `eval()` is vulnerable to code injection. In itself, it like uses the `float()` anyway.